# relation between topologies

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I Came across this question recently. Could someone help me out with this.
Let T1 be the smallest topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ containing the sets $(a,b)\times (c, d)$ for all $a,b, c, d$ in $\mathbb{R}$

Let T2 be the smallest topology containing the sets $\{(x,y) : (x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 < c,\text{ for all } a, b\in\mathbb{R} \text{ and } c>0\}$

Let T3 be the smallest topology containing the sets $\{(x, y) : |x-a|+ |y-b| < c,\text{ for all }a, b\in\mathbb{R}\text{ and }c>0\}$

What is the relation between the three?

Comment: Could you tell us what this problem is for? What have you attempted so far?

Comment: Also, presumably the last two sets should have their right bracket after the inequality?

Comment: Have you drawn the sets in these collections? What are they?

Answer (score 1):

Do you know  this lemma?

**Lemma.** Let $\cal{B}_1$ and $\cal{B}_2$ bases for topologies $\cal{T}_1$ and $\cal{T}_2$ on the same set $X$. Assume that for every $B \in \cal{B}_1$ and every point $x\in B$ there exists some $B'\in \cal{B}_2$ such that $x\in B' \subset B$. Then $\cal{T}_2$ is *finner* than $\cal{T}_1$.

This means that all open sets for topology $\cal{T}_1$ are also open sets fot topology $\cal{T}_2$.

As a corollary, if we also have that for every $B'\in \cal{B}_2$ and every point $x\in B'$ there exists $B \in \cal{B}_1$ such that $x\in B \subset B'$, then we conclude that both topologies are equal, have the same open sets.

If you don't know the lemma, we can discuss its proof later on. For the moment, let's focus on this: would you be able to apply it for your topologies? (Those collections of sets of yours are bases for your topologies $\cal{T}_1,\cal{T}_2  $ and $\cal{T}_3 $, respectively.)

**Hint.** As Henno Brandsma suggests you, draw those sets.

Comment: I think i can use this for the problem. It was in a NET question paper